# I can't Link my angular.min.js file to the Laravel master.blade.php file since its not working?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.frontend.master')
@section('content')
    <div class="container container-content">

            <h2> Apply online </h2>
            <div  class="well">

            <form role="" class="form-horizontal" action="" name="myapp">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div ng-app="myapp">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="name"><p> @{{ name }}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

master.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url::asset('angular/angular.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ url::asset('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js')}}"></script>

<!--endo fo js file-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    @section('header')
    {!! view('layout/frontend/header') !!}
    @stop


    @section('footer')
    {!! view('layout/frontend/footer')!!}
    @stop

    @yield('header')
    @yield('content')
    @yield('footer')

    </div></body></html>
```

Since i wanted the binding of angular js but its not working i can't bind the input and only following is displayed

{{ name }}

since i use @ before the {{ to avoid laravel confliciton but its not working.
Please provide me proper solution
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use

```
    url::asset('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js')
```

The link is not an asset, as in its not placed in your asset folder, just put in in plainly:

```
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"
```

Comment: Thats also Not Working . I can't link my angular.min.js file??